# blob size on client sometimes is smaller then the file sent from server

Tags: node.js, express, blob, fetch-api

I have a pdf file on a server that i want to send to the client. I'm using expressjs on the server and this is the code wirte and serve the file:

```
function writeFile(fileStream, fileName) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var file = fs.createWriteStream(fileName);
        fileStream.pipe(file);
        filestream.on('finish', () => {

            resolve();
        });;
    });
}
            ...
            writeFile(fileStream, params.file).then(function() {
                ftps.end();

                console.log(params.file);

                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');

                res.status(200).download(`./${params.file}`, params.file, (err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        res.status(500).send({
                            message: "Could not download the file. " + err,
                        });
                    }

                    var stats = fs.statSync(params.file);
                    console.log(stats.size);
    
                    fs.unlink(`./${params.file}`, function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            throw err
                        } else {
                            console.log("Successfully deleted the file.")
                        }
                    });
                });
    
            });
```

and then client side to retrieve the file:

```
let toParse = await fetch(self.apiLink, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(self.params)
            });

            l(toParse.status);

            if (toParse.status == 200) {
                let parsed;
                if (fileExpected) parsed = await toParse.blob();
                else parsed = await toParse.json();
                hideLoader();
                l(parsed);
                return parsed;
            }

var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(toParse);
$('#pdf_frame').attr("src",url);

window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

Everything is working as intended except that sometimes the file on the client is a little smaller in size and doesn't get displayed. I have no clue on why this is happening and cannot find any answer on the internet

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake:

```
function writeFile(fileStream, fileName) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var file = fs.createWriteStream(fileName);
        fileStream.pipe(file);
        filestream.on('finish', () => { //this should be concat to filestream.pipe(file)

        resolve();
        });;
    });
}
```

so the solution:

```
function writeFile(fileStream, fileName) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var file = fs.createWriteStream(fileName);
        fileStream.pipe(file).on('finish', () => {

            resolve();
        });;
    });
}
```

Now blob size is consistent between server and client